# padding_medium cannot be resolved or is not a field error

Tags: android, android-fragments, actionbarsherlock, android-viewpager

I have a view pager to view images in Swipe horizontal fashion. I am populating view pager with my ImageFragmentAdapter class which extends FragmentPagerAdapter. In my ImageFragmentAdapter .java, i am gettin an error in this line

```
int padding = context.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.padding_medium);

Error is : padding_medium cannot be resolved or is not a field
```

I just googled about the issue, I came to know that i should add this line to imports.

```
import your.application.packagename.R;
```

But still i get error on this line. can anyone tell what is the problem.?

```
ImageFragmentAdapter .java


    public class ImageFragmentAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter implements
            IconPagerAdapter 
            {

         private int[] CONTENT = new int[] {
                R.drawable.gallery_photo_1,
                R.drawable.gallery_photo_2,
                R.drawable.gallery_photo_3,
                R.drawable.gallery_photo_4
            };


        protected static final int[] ICONS = new int[] { R.drawable.marker,
                R.drawable.marker, R.drawable.marker, R.drawable.marker };

        private int mCount = CONTENT.length;

        public ImageFragmentAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return ImageFragment.newInstance(CONTENT[position % CONTENT.length]);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mCount;
        }

         @Override
            public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
              Context context = MainActivity.appContext;
              ImageView imageView = new ImageView(context);
              int padding = context.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(
                      R.dimen.padding_medium);//error//
              imageView.setPadding(padding, padding, padding, padding);
              imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);
              imageView.setImageResource(CONTENT[position]);
              ((ViewPager) container).addView(imageView, 0);
              return imageView;
            }
        @Override
        public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
          return view == ((ImageView) object);
        }
        @Override
        public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
          ((ViewPager) container).removeView((ImageView) object);
        }
        /*
        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return ImageFragmentAdapter.CONTENT[position % CONTENT.length];
        }
    */
        @Override
        public int getIconResId(int index) {
            return ICONS[index % ICONS.length];
        }

        public void setCount(int count) {
            if (count > 0 && count <= 10) {
                mCount = count;
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }
    }
```

I use DetailsFragment.java to populate the View pager onto fragment_details.xml

```
public class DetailsFragment extends SherlockFragment 
{
     public static final String TAG = "detailsFragment";

    ImageFragmentAdapter mAdapter;
    ViewPager mPager;
    PageIndicator mIndicator;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        //container.removeAllViews();
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_details, container,
                false);

        mAdapter = new ImageFragmentAdapter(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager());

        mPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        mIndicator = (CirclePageIndicator) view.findViewById(R.id.indicator);
        mIndicator.setViewPager(mPager);

        return view;
    }

}
```

fragment_details.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <com.viewpagerindicator.CirclePageIndicator
        android:id="@+id/indicator"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dip" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Please post your dimens.xml file where you are defining this dimension.